# Populate List<String> with AlertDialog Input

Tags: android, arrays, list, android-alertdialog, illegalstateexception

Building my first app and can't find a solution by myself.

What my app does:

- MainActivity prompts user to input player amount
- presses Ok, input passed to next activity

now I want, that the user is prompted to input the player names, one by one with an `AlertDialog`. Those names, should be stored in an Array.

My code so far:

```
public class MainScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainScreen.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);

        try {

            Intent intent = getIntent();
            final int sumPlayers = getIntent().getIntExtra("sumPlayers", 0);
            final List<String> playerNames = new ArrayList<>();

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            final EditText input = new EditText(getBaseContext());
            input.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            //input.setSingleLine();

            for (int c=0; c<sumPlayers; c++) {

                builder.setTitle("Input Player Name");
                builder.setView(input);

                builder.setPositiveButton("ADD", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        playerNames.add(input.getText().toString());
                    }
                });

                builder.show();
            }

            ArrayAdapter<String> playerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.player_list_item, R.id.editText, playerNames);
            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_main);

            listView.setAdapter(playerAdapter);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("2te Act");
            Log.e(TAG, "Error@: ", e);
        }
    }
}
```

I get this Exception @ `builder.show()`;

> Java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

It's working without the for loop except one minor problem.
When I set the input field to `setSingleLine();` the `listView` stays empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a single `AlertDialog.Builder` and repeatedly setting the title, view, and positive button with different values. You likely need to move this logic inside the `for` loop:

```
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final EditText input = new EditText(getBaseContext());
        input.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        //input.setSingleLine();
```